# How to process queue of tasks parallely in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have files which need to be uploaded somewhere for processing. File paths resides in a database table.

In Sequential programming I fetch the bunch of 20(may be n) files and upload these files for processing and delete these files and then process next slot of 20 files.

But what i need is upload these files parallely like performing task parallely with **TPL in C#**(Parallel.For etc.). This can be achieved easily in TPL but I have to wait for all the tasks.

For example in my task queue I have 20 files and 19 files in this queue have size 1 MB but 1 file has size 500 MB.

So when I use **Parallel.For** on this queue multiple threads start uploading these files. In this case 19 files which have smaller size will be uploaded faster but 1 file with large size will take time.

So what I need is while processing the larger file can I enter 19 other files in queue and start processing them too in parallel of that large file.

Comment: You really should check out [TPL DataFlow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as it fits your requirements very nicely.

Comment: Are you sure you need to upload them in **parallel**, rather than **async**?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the overload of `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach` which accepts a parameter of type `ParallelOptions`.

For example (using `ForEach`):

```
ParallelOptions opts = new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20};
Parallel.ForEach(files, opts, process);
```

Where `files` is the list of filenames and  `process` is declared like this:

```
private static void process(string file)
{
    ...
```

This will limit the `ForEach` to `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` (in this case, 20) simultaneous threads, and as soon as one finishes it will schedule a new one, until it runs out of items to schedule.